# pq: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "$1" with Golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to do a simple `INSERT` into a `postgresql` database in my `GO` program. I have the number `0` that is a `float64`, I have a column in my database that expects `double precision`. I have no idea what I need to convert the number to in order for the database to accept the value.

Comment: What exact error message do you have and is there a code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The exact error message is `pq: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "$1"` and to reproduce the problem, try inserting a float64 value into a postgres database column that expects a double float.

Comment: Or any value that isn't whatever pg expects when a column is double precision.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote? I'm sure others will get this error, and I can't find anything else on the internet to help solve the problem. If you're going to down vote, at least give constructive feedback.

Comment: `float with no precision specified is taken to mean double precision.` If you define column type as float in db, should be fine. I haven't tried with more precision before so if you really need precision, I guess you need to use something from `math/big` and implement `Scan` and `Value` for your named type. Otherwise, you will lose precision in go part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL driver handles insertion of float64 into double precision columns quite well:

```
tmp=# \d test
          Table "public.test"
 Column |       Type       | Modifiers 
--------+------------------+-----------
 v      | double precision |
```

And code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=alex dbname=tmp sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    result, err := db.Exec("insert into test values ($1)", float64(0.5))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

And then:

```
tmp=# select * from test ;
  v  
-----
 0.5
 0.5
 0.5
(3 rows)
```

The question was downvoted because obviously the problem description you provided is *not enough* to reproduce the issue. I've tried to follow but as you see it is working.

Comment: You're right, I noticed after going for a walk that I was passing variables as '$1' instead of $1. I should have included a code example.